# Excel multiple criteria lookup referring to its own row

Tags: excel, criteria, lookup

Typical multiple criteria index-match array formula is no brainer if you use kind of a form next to the dataset and the criteria are in static positions. What I need, and can't make it to work is the mechanism to look into its own current row for one of the criteria. To each row I need to assign the "waga" value matching same timestamp as the currant row.

I came up with an array formula, but its wrong, I don;t know how to properly substitute the C:C part

=INDEX(D2:D81;MATCH(1;(B2:B81="waga")*(C2:C81=C:C);0);4)

```
ID  Type    Timestamp   Value
1   zak_lvids   42251,42639 18,5
2   zak_lvpwd   42251,42639 4,3
3   wylicz_ef   42251,42639 62,85
4   wylicz_sf   42251,42639 33,91
5   sr_ao   42251,42639 19,8
6   wsk_lvids   42251,42639 
7   pom_lvpws   42251,42639 7
8   waga    42251,42639 24,5
9   zak_lvpwd_h 42251,42639 8
10  sr_lvpwd    42251,42639 5,9
11  zak_rvdd_h  42251,42639 16,8
12  sr_lvidd    42251,42639 36,4
13  zak_ao  42251,42639 16,1
14  zak_ivsd_h  42251,42639 7,7
15  pom_lvpwd   42251,42639 5,4
16  wylicz_lvdv 42251,42639 98,8
17  zak_lvidd_h 42251,42639 44
18  zak_rvdd    42251,42639 5,4
19  zak_lvids_h 42251,42639 29,9
20  sr_ivsd 42251,42639 5,7
21  pom_ivss    42251,42639 8,3
22  sr_lvids    42251,42639 23,5
23  zak_la_h    42251,42639 30,6
24  zak_lvidd   42251,42639 30,1
25  sr_la   42251,42639 23,8
26  pom_ivsd    42251,42639 5,4
27  zak_la  42251,42639 18,5
28  wylicz_lvm  42251,42639 72,8
29  wylicz_lvsv 42251,42639 36,7
30  pom_lvidd   42251,42639 46,3
31  wsk_lvidd   42251,42639 
32  sr_rvdd 42251,42639 11,1
33  zak_ao_h    42251,42639 24,3
34  pom_lvids   42251,42639 30,6
35  zak_ivsd    42251,42639 3,8
36  zak_lvids   42258,56319 18,5
37  zak_lvpwd   42258,56319 4,3
38  wylicz_ef   42258,56319 60,82
39  wylicz_sf   42258,56319 32,44
40  sr_ao   42258,56319 19,8
41  wsk_lvids   42258,56319 
42  pom_lvpws   42258,56319 7,2
43  waga    42258,56319 22
44  wylicz_lvmi 42258,56319 44,1
45  zak_lvpwd_h 42258,56319 8
46  sr_lvpwd    42258,56319 5,9
47  zak_rvdd_h  42258,56319 16,8
48  sr_lvidd    42258,56319 36,4
49  zak_ao  42258,56319 16,1
50  zak_ivsd_h  42258,56319 7,7
51  pom_lvpwd   42258,56319 5,8
52  wylicz_lvdv 42258,56319 92,4
53  zak_lvidd_h 42258,56319 44
54  zak_rvdd    42258,56319 5,4
55  zak_lvids_h 42258,56319 29,9
56  sr_ivsd 42258,56319 5,7
57  pom_ivss    42258,56319 7,6
58  sr_lvids    42258,56319 23,5
59  bsa 42258,56319 0,91
60  zak_la_h    42258,56319 30,6
61  zak_lvidd   42258,56319 30,1
62  sr_la   42258,56319 23,8
63  pom_ivsd    42258,56319 5,8
64  zak_la  42258,56319 18,5
65  wylicz_lvm  42258,56319 75,5
66  wylicz_lvsv 42258,56319 36,2
67  pom_lvidd   42258,56319 45
68  wsk_lvidd   42258,56319 
69  sr_rvdd 42258,56319 11,1
70  zak_ao_h    42258,56319 24,3
71  pom_lvids   42258,56319 30,4
72  wzrost  42258,56319 122
73  zak_ivsd    42258,56319 3,8
74  bmi 42258,56319 16,46
```

Comment: Change the `C:C` to `C2` or what ever row in which you first place the formula then drag down.  Make sure to make the other references absolute e.g `D2:D81` should be `$D$2:$D$81` do that to the other references.  Leave the `C2` as `C2` Hit Ctrl-Shift-enter then drag down.

Comment: So the first formula should be `=INDEX($D$2:$D$81;MATCH(1;($B$2:$B$81="waga")*($C$2:$C$81=C2);0))` Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then drag down

Comment: You're right with the absolute ref's - that I have tried at first. THE BIG TRICK THAT I DIDN'T KNOW OF is to Ctrl-Shift-enter in the first cell alone and only than to drag it! - I tried like with an ordinary array funcion to Ctrl-Shift-enter it for the whole column at onece! Now I know it couldn't have worked! THANKS ALOT! For a 10000 times (that's about how deeep is my table).